# How do I develop an online survey application?

Tags: asp.net

I want to develop application that contain number of question with independent radiobuttonlist which contain three option Yes, No, Unsure.

Daily visitors comes on the site & reply to the question. Also to show addition of the Yes, NO & Unsure in front of each question.

Please give me idea how to do such functionalty.

Regards,
Girish

Comment: I am tempted to vote to close this question, as it is way to broad. What are you struggling with? Do you need help with database connectivity? With asp.net controls? Html? Postbacks?

Comment: look at an existing one http://surveymaster.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 2):

Quickest and easiest way would be to piggy-back on an existing site.

http://www.polldaddy.com/ will allow you to embed polls in your own site

Comment: The question is broad and vague, but I think he states that he wants to "develop application", not use an existing service.  Vote down.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very vague question and probably won't get much of an answer.

What technology do you want to use, .Net, Java. PHP etc, what resources do you have available?

Essentially you need some sort of database to store the questions and answers in and a front end web application built in whatever technology you decide on (as stated .net, Java or PHP are probably the most common).

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom control that uses an Update Panel.  Inside the update Panel you will have two PlaceHolders - 1 for your questions and 1 for your results.  Hide the results placeholder by default.  Once the radiobutton (OnSelectedIndexChanged) is selected, cause a postback and calculate the results.  In the same Postback method, hide the Question placeholder and show the results placeholder with the calculated results.

Your page could look like this:

```
<UpdatePanel ID="upPanel" runat="server">
<ContentTemplate>

<asp:PlaceHolder ID="plcQuestion" runat="server">
 Have you ever written asp.net code?
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="radList" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="doStuff">
   <asp:ListItem>Yes</asp:ListItem>
   <asp:ListItem>No</asp:ListItem>
   <asp:ListItem>Unsure</asp:ListItem>
</asp:RadioButtonList>
</asp:PLaceholder>

<asp:PlaceHolder ID="plcAnswers" runat="server" Visible="false">
 Results:
 Yes: <asp:Label ID="lblYesResults" runat="server" />
 No: <asp:Label ID="lblNoResults" runat="server" />
 Unsure: <asp:Label ID="lblUnsureResults" runat="server" /> 
</asp:PLaceholder>

</ContentTemplate>
</UpdatePanel>
```

Then, on your "doStuff" method, just save the results and populate whatever result display you are going for.   Hope this helps!